# How to call other constructors from a constructor in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a constructor like:

```
public Blah(string a, string b)
{

}

public Blah(string a, string b, string c)
{
  this.a =a;
  this.b =b;
  this.c =c;
}
```

How can I call the 2nd constructor from the 1st one?

like:

```
public Blah(string a, string b)
{
   Blah(a,b, "");
}
```

Comment: BTW, that's generally referred to as constructor chaining.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public Blah(string a, string b) : this(a, b, "")
{
}

public Blah(string a, string b, string c)
{
    // etc
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `String.Empty` instead of ""

Comment: @abatishchev: Do you have a reference for that? As far as I'm concerned it's just down to personal preference and what you find more readable. I prefer `""`.

Comment: "" (potentially) creates an object, String.empty doesn't.

Comment: @Anders: `object.ReferenceEquals("", string.Empty)` evaluates as true on my machine - ie, they're the same interned string object. (And even if that isn't always the case, I can live with one extra, tiny interned string per assembly.)

Comment: yep, has very little practical impact in most cases

Answer (score 5):

```
public Blah(string a, string b): this(a, b, String.Empty)
{

}

public Blah(string a, string b, string c)
{
  this.a =a;
  this.b =b;
  this.c =c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Blah(string a, string b) : this(a,b, "default_C_String")
{ 

}
```

--- whatever your desired default value is for C ...

Answer (score -2):

public Blah(string a, string b): this(a, b, String.Empty)
{

}